# How can I test a button on my Facebook Ads?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads

I have created an ad in Facebook to point to the Google Play Store.

Now I would like to test, if when someone clicks on the button, it really works. Is there a way to test the ad?

There is a preview mode for ads, but this only shows the layout of the ad on several display types, but how can I have a real preview with functionality for my ad?